# How to parse json in php?

Tags: php, json

I am trying to parse this json  `'{"options":"[{\"order\":\"1\"},{\"skill\":\"\\n                        wajghjk                    \"},{\"order\":\"2\"},{\"skill\":\"\\n                        aswedrty                    \"},{\"order\":\"3\"},{\"skill\":\"\\n                        skill1                    \"},{\"order\":\"4\"},{\"skill\":\"\\n                        wasedjk                    \"},{\"order\":\"5\"},{\"skill\":\"\\n                        Feldsher                    \"},{\"order\":\"6\"},{\"skill\":\"\\n                        wasedjk                    \"},{\"order\":\"7\"},{\"skill\":\"\\n                        Autotransfusionist                    \"},{\"order\":\"8\"},{\"skill\":\"\\n                        Feldsher                    \"},{\"order\":\"9\"},{\"skill\":\"\\n                        Autotransfusionist                    \"}]"}'`   . using the code

```
<?php
$json = '{"options":"[{\"order\":\"1\"},{\"skill\":\"\\n                        wajghjk                    \"},{\"order\":\"2\"},{\"skill\":\"\\n                        aswedrty                    \"},{\"order\":\"3\"},{\"skill\":\"\\n                        skill1                    \"},{\"order\":\"4\"},{\"skill\":\"\\n                        wasedjk                    \"},{\"order\":\"5\"},{\"skill\":\"\\n                        Feldsher                    \"},{\"order\":\"6\"},{\"skill\":\"\\n                        wasedjk                    \"},{\"order\":\"7\"},{\"skill\":\"\\n                        Autotransfusionist                    \"},{\"order\":\"8\"},{\"skill\":\"\\n                        Feldsher                    \"},{\"order\":\"9\"},{\"skill\":\"\\n                        Autotransfusionist                    \"}]"}';

$decode = json_decode($json, true);
$a=array();
echo '<br/>';
foreach($decode['options'] as $a)
{
    echo $a['order'];echo '<br/>';
     echo $a['skill'];echo '<br/>';
}
?>
```

But it is showing error and not able to parse . Is there any better way to get the values of order and skill from this json ?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Could you link the error?

Comment: You should remove the backslashes

Comment: if you paste it in http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ you'll see what you have isn't well-formed JSON.

Comment: Iam getting the error as    Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 12

Comment: At first glance, `options` has been assigned a _string_: `options": "[{\"order...` <-- see the double quote that precedes the bracket? `:"[{\"`? That shouldn't be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're escaping your double quotes, which will come out as literal `\` characters when the string is delimited by single quotes.

Either run [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) on the json string, or avoid the escaping in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

That's not JSON. You are escaping too many double quotes.

Comment: Check this out to see whether you have valid JSON or not: http://json.parser.online.fr/

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems with the json string.

1. You escape double quotes inside single-quoted string. But single-quoted string has only one escape sequence and that is \'. [Check this article](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single).
2. You have a problem here: `'{"options":"[{...}]"}'`. You enclosed javascript [array] with quotes, which turned it into a string.

The correct json should look like this:

```
{"options":[{"order":"1"},{"skill":"\\n wajghjk "},{"order":"2"},{"skill":"\\n aswedrty "},{"order":"3"},{"skill":"\\n skill1 "},{"order":"4"},{"skill":"\\n wasedjk "},{"order":"5"},{"skill":"\\n Feldsher "},{"order":"6"},{"skill":"\\n wasedjk "},{"order":"7"},{"skill":"\\n Autotransfusionist "},{"order":"8"},{"skill":"\\n Feldsher "},{"order":"9"},{"skill":"\\n Autotransfusionist "}]}
```

[Eval.in demo](https://eval.in/38538)

Answer (score 1):

> it is showing error and not able to parse .

PHP is quite weak in debugging json. All you can do is

```
$json_errors = array(
    "",
    "The maximum stack depth has been exceeded",
    "Invalid or malformed JSON",
    "Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded",
    "Syntax error",
    "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded",
);

$decode = json_decode($json, true);
if ($error = json_last_error())
{
    trigger_error($json_errors[$error]);
}
```

Though, in order to get values you have to have a valid json string, not just arbitrary string consists of some quotes and slashes.

And of course you should **never ever** create a json string manually.